# How to display rows that have the same column value (ASP.NET Core / SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

My database table `Alerting` looks like this:

[image]

My model is:

```
public class AlertingResponseDB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Instance { get; set; }
    public string Serverity { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ActiveAt { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the function I wrote - this function returns all the data ordered by instance:

```
    //getting alerting historic
    [HttpGet("getByInstance/{ip}&{port}")]
    public async Task<dynamic> GetAlertingByInstance(string ip,string port)
    {
        string _instance = ip + ":" + port;
        var alerting = await _context.Alertings.OrderBy(e => e.Instance).ToListAsync();
        var Allvalues = _mapper.ProjectTo<AlertingResponseDB>(alerting.AsQueryable()).ToList();

        return Allvalues;
    }
```

**Problem:** I want to get only the rows from the `Alerting` table with the same instance name and display it.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's **severity** - not "Serverity" .. (no "r" before the "v")

Comment: I made a mistake when I was typing thanks man ! :D

Comment: Looks like I found the solution, should I remove this post or leave it ?

Comment: You can post an answer yourself to explain how you've solved this - maybe someone else will stumble over the same problem, and be thankful to find a solution to it here (unless it's just a typo or something ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my first time answering, I want to share the solution that I found with you.
In the function I had to parse all the rows that have the same instance values, I'm using Entity Framework: `.Where()`.
So my function after I have made changes:

```
    //getting alerting historic by instance
    [HttpGet("getByInstance/{ip}&{port}")]
    public async Task<dynamic> GetAlertingByInstance(string ip,string port)
    {
        string _instance = ip + ":" + port;
        var alertingPerInstance = await _context.Alertings.Where(e => e.Instance == _instance).ToListAsync();

        return alertingPerInstance;
    }
```